# How to find keccak256 / sha256 of a struct?

Tags: solidity

it turns out sha256(a) != sha256(b);

How is sha256() implemented?

```js
struct B {
    byte x;
}

struct A {
    byte x;
}
byte x = 0x0;
A memory a = A(x = x);
B memory b = B(x = x);
```

Comment: I don't think hashing of structs is supported yet: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/980

Comment: What is it, that you are trying to achieve exactly?